# css percentage width and height on header

Tags: html, css

I want to have a fluid header so I used percentage.

**Prerequisite:**

1) I will call it the "basic" which is a div containing some essential link/img. This will take up 15% in total width and will resize itself depends on browser size.

2) The rest will call "nav" which is also a div. They are also some link and will be added over time. "nav" will take up the left over width with is 85% (100%width - 15% basic)

3) As "nav" link increases to a certain amount, it will push to the next line.

4) It is better off to be supported in I.E. 7 and above?

5) Its best to not use float

**Tried solution:** 
1) Putting html comment line in-between div because sometimes html space mess up alignment.

2) Putting margin 0 and padding 0 for everything to check if its the reason.

Question: How do I have a percentage header which "basic" div take up 15% and a "nav" div take the rest of 85% and when "nav" div's link overflow it will push to the next line?

I have made a `JsFiddle` as following.

[JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ydpu79vj/)

Comment: What's your question?  I don't see one anywhere.

Comment: This smells like homework....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could float the div with `class="basic"` to `float:left` and the div with `class="nav"` have `margin-left:15%`. Also, will need to **remove** the **width:85%** from the div with class nav.

[JsFiddle sample](https://jsfiddle.net/ydpu79vj/1/)

Might not be a simple fix without the float on div `class="basic"`

Hope this helps.